# Node.js fs.stat [TypeError: path must be a string] on passing Buffer

Tags: node.js, fs

According to documentation for **fs.stat** [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback), `stat` function can accept a string path to a file OR a buffer.

But when I passed a Buffer, I am getting an error:

> [TypeError: path must be a string]

Below is the code.

```
exports.importNow = function (req, res) {
try {
      fs.stat( req.files.csv.buffer, function (err, stat) {
          if( err == null ) {
              console.log(2);
              return resolve();
          } else {
              console.log(3);
              return reject( [validation_errors.FILE_DOES_NOT_EXIST, err] );
          }
      });

    } catch ( err ) {
      console.log(5);
      console.log(err);
      return reject( [validation_errors.FILE_DOES_NOT_EXIST, err] );
    }
}
```

Cann anybody please help me find the reason? Or am I missing anything?
Thank you.

Comment: What version of node are you running? (Run `node --version` to find out if you don't know)

Comment: Hi Frxstrem, The node version I am using is - v4.6.2

Answer (score 1):

You're using an old version of Node.js (newest is v7.9.0, oldest supported is v6.0.0).

The file system APIs has only supported buffers since v6.0.0 ([see changelog](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V6.md#2016-04-26-version-600-current-jasnell)). For earlier versions, you'll need to convert the buffer to a string:

```js
fs.stat( req.files.csv.buffer.toString(), function (err, stat) {
  // ...
});
```

You should either upgrade to Node.js v6.0.0 or later (which I recommend if possible), or be using the documentation for [v4.6](https://nodejs.org/docs/v4.6.0/api/fs.html) (since the documentation you linked to is for the latest version, which will be different from your version).

Comment: I updated node.js. Now it is 7.*
But still I am getting this error.
`{
    "errno": -36,
    "code": "ENAMETOOLONG",
    "syscall": "stat",
"path" : ...`

Answer (score 0):

It wants a path. The path can be  |  | , but it needs to be a path.